# Making an object appear to move across the screen randomly

Tags: xna

I'm currently doing an assignment, on which one of the requirements is for a random object to appear on screen and move across. Being new to XNA, i do not know where to even begin implementing such behaviours to the game, thus would really appreciate if someone could give me a nudge towards the right direction.

I'm only really accustomed to invoking something when a key is pressed, however with something completely random, this can't be done. as far as i am aware of.

Thank you.

Comment: Try it, and if you have any *specific* problems, feel free to ask another question.

Comment: Well, the problem is, i don't know where to start. I have my game done, most of it. it's just this one requirement, making an object move randomly across the screen, not a fixed time which is hurting my head.

Comment: One of the problems is that you haven't explained your issue well enough. Are you trying to display a random image moving at a random speed? Are you meaning that fixed time step is off? You need to provide more details.

Comment: I want to display a flying saucer to appear on the screen at a random time when the game is running, moving vertically across the screen until it reaches the end, at which point it should disappear.

Comment: Wow, you've just written down the exact solution to the problem :) It's only as if you're unaware that there is a `Random` class built into .NET, which gives you random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create and set up a sprite for the UFO first. In your  protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime) code you simply need to get the current time and compare it to the rules in which you wish to apply. Then update if you wish to draw and "move" the sprite. Here is an example:

```
#region Using Statements
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;
#endregion
 public class Game : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game {
        #region Game Settings
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        GraphicsDevice device;
        int screenWidth         = 800;
        int screenHeight        = 600;
        bool fullscreen         = false;
        string title            = "MyGame";
        string origionaltitle;
        float frames            = 0;
        float framesPerSecond   = 0;
        int startTime;
        int currentTime;
        int nextTime;
        #endregion
        struct sprite {

            public string TextureName;
            public Texture2D Texture;
            public Vector2 Position;
            public Vector2 Speed;
            public Color[] TextureData;
        };
        bool DrawUFO = false;
        sprite ufo = new sprite();
        public Game() {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }
        protected override void LoadContent() {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            device = graphics.GraphicsDevice;
            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
            ufo.TextureName = "ufo";
            ufo.Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>(ball.TextureName);
            ufo.TextureData = new Color[ufo.Texture.Width *ufo.Texture.Height];
            ufo.Texture.GetData(ball.TextureData); 
        }
         protected override void Initialize() {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
            ufo.Position = new Vector2(10f, 10.0f);
            ufo.Speed = new Vector2(0.0f, 10.0f);
            //
            // Set up game window
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = screenWidth;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = screenHeight;
            graphics.IsFullScreen = fullscreen;
            graphics.ApplyChanges();
            origionaltitle = title;
            Window.Title = title;
            //
            // Set the initial time
            startTime = DateTime.Now.Second;
            //
            // Set "random"/next time for ufo to be rendered
            nextTime = startTime + rand.Next(2);
            //
            base.Initialize();
        }
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime) {
            //
            // Set the current time
            currentTime = DateTime.Now.Second;
            //
            // if not drawing ufo then
            if(!DrawURO) {
                // 
                // check current time and compare it with the next time
                if( currentTime == nextTime ) {
                    DrawURO = true;
                }
            } else {
                //
                // Update UFO position (aka move it)
                ufo.Posistion += ball.Speed *(float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
                //
                // if ufo goes of the screen then
                if(ufo.Position.Y > screenHeight) {
                    //
                    // Reset ufo
                    DrawURO = false;
                    ufo.Position.X = 10.0f;
                    ufo.Position.Y = 10.0f;
                    //
                    // set next time to render
                    nextTime = currentTime + rand.Next(2);
                }

            }
        }
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime) {
            graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
            // TODO: Add your drawing code here
            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteBlendMode.AlphaBlend);
            if(DrawUFO == true) {
                spriteBatch.Draw(ufo.Texture, ufo.Position, Color.White);
            }
            spriteBatch.End();
            //
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
 }
```

I copied this from some code i did at college a few years a ago, so apologies for any bugs.